# React useState(), Why can't we update the previous value object and return it directly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rxjs

I tried the following code but it did not work and I don't really understand the reason for it. Wanted to display the first name, last name and email. But with the following code it does not render.

```js
// prevValue[name] = value;
// return prevValue;
```

I know the better option is using spread method. but just wondering why doesn't it render up?

Expected outcome:

[image: Expected outcome]

```js
import React, {
  useState
} from "react";

function App() {
  const [contact, setContact] = useState({
    fName: "",
    lName: "",
    email: ""
  });

  function handleContact(event) {
    const {
      value,
      name
    } = event.target;

    setContact((prevValue) => {
      // prevValue[name] = value;
      // return prevValue;

      /*Logged result
      {fName: "a", lName: "", email: ""}
      {fName: "s", lName: "", email: ""}
      {fName: "d", lName: "", email: ""}*/

      if (name === "fName") {
        return {
          fName: value,
          lName: prevValue.lName,
          email: prevValue.email
        };
      }
    });
    /*Logged result
    {fName: "", lName: "", email: ""}
    {fName: "a", lName: "", email: ""}
    {fName: "as", lName: "", email: ""}*/
    console.log(contact);
  }

  return ( <
    div className = "container" >
    <
    h1 >
    Hello {
      contact.fName
    } {
      contact.lName
    } <
    /h1> <
    p > {
      contact.email
    } < /p> <
    form >
    <
    input name = "fName"
    placeholder = "First Name"
    value = {
      contact.fName
    }
    onChange = {
      handleContact
    }
    /> <
    input name = "lName"
    placeholder = "Last Name"
    value = {
      contact.lName
    }
    onChange = {
      handleContact
    }
    /> <
    input name = "email"
    placeholder = "Email"
    value = {
      contact.email
    }
    onChange = {
      handleContact
    }
    /> <
    button > Submit < /button> <
    /form> <
    /div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to notify the dom, that the object has been changed by recreating it or iterating it. See the snippet below.

```js
function App() {
  const [contact, setContact] = React.useState({
    fName: "",
    lName: "",
    email: ""
  });

  function handleContact(event) {
    const { value, name } = event.target;
    setContact((prevValue) => {
      prevValue[name] = value;
      return { ...prevValue };
    });
  }
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>
        Hello {contact.fName} {contact.lName}{" "}
      </h1>
      <p> {contact.email} </p>
      <form>
        <input
          name="fName"
          placeholder="First Name"
          value={contact.fName}
          onChange={handleContact}
        />
        <input
          name="lName"
          placeholder="Last Name"
          value={contact.lName}
          onChange={handleContact}
        />{" "}
        <input
          name="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          value={contact.email}
          onChange={handleContact}
        />{" "}
        <button> Submit </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: i did render my <App /> but its in another file. Interestingly  

return prevValue; doesn't work 

but 

return { ...prevValue }; work instead.

hoping there is an explanation for this? thanks!

Comment: Simply it is like this, react will assign a reference for the object, although the nested values being changed the reference is the same. So react won't identify it as changed (This will affect for arrays and objects). But by iterating the object, react will identify it as new object. Hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `setContact`, You get the previous value of state as an argument

And you have the option to use the previous value of state to return the new desired value of state `contact`

For setting the firstName, You can do something like this

```
setContact(prev => {...contact, firstName: value})
```

So the `onChange` handler for the `<input />` can be

```
const handleFirstNameChange = () => {
   setContact(prev => {...contact, firstName: value})
}
```

But you dont want to write three such handlers for `firstName`, `lastName` and `emailAddress` just to update your contact state variable

So you can write a single wrapper function like

```
const handleContactChange = (attr, val){
   setContact(prev => {...contact, attr: val})
}
```